# Target class [ProdutosController] does not exist

Tags: php, lavarel

Sou novo com PHP e Laravel e estou travado em um erro quando tento carregar a página.
Aparece o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Modelo:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'custo', 'preco', 'quantidade'];
    use HasFactory;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProdutosController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('produtos.create');
    }

}
```

**View** (create.blade.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Cadastrar um novo produto</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for="">Nome</label> <br />
        <input type="text" name="nome"> <br />
        <label for="">Custo</label> <br />
        <input type="text" name="custo"> <br />
        <label for="">Preço</label> <br />
        <input type="text" name="preco"> <br />
        <label for="">Quantidade</label> <br />
        <input type="text" name="quantidade"> <br />
        <button>Salvar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Router:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/produtos/novo', 'ProdutosController@create');
```

Digitei o comando `PHP artisan route:list` e apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Digite no terminal PHP artisan route:list verifique se apareceu a rota

Comment: Obrigado @novic, atualizei minha pergunta com o resultado do comando PHP artisan route:list, consegue me ajudar a descobrir o erro?

Comment: Achei a solução, bastou alterar o route para Route::get('/produtos/novo', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProdutosController@create');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução**

Alterei o **Router** para:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/produtos/novo', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProdutosController@create');
```

Comment: Bom dia. O correto era o namespace padrão estar configurado para não digitar o caminho completo do controller.